# Логи ошибок tomcat

Tags: tomcat, логирование

Запускаю проект из idea.
Командой `sudo lsof | grep -E "java.*(out|txt|log)$"` выяснил что логи живут в `~/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed_hellomvc/logs`

их список:

```
 total 128
-rw-r----- 1 vpotseluyko vpotseluyko 32196 янв 21 23:50 catalina.2017-01-21.log
-rw-r----- 1 vpotseluyko vpotseluyko 83853 янв 22 00:54 catalina.2017-01-22.log
-rw-r----- 1 vpotseluyko vpotseluyko     0 янв 21 21:32 host-manager.2017-01-21.log
-rw-r----- 1 vpotseluyko vpotseluyko     0 янв 22 00:19 host-manager.2017-01-22.log
-rw-r----- 1 vpotseluyko vpotseluyko     0 янв 21 21:32 localhost.2017-01-21.log
-rw-r----- 1 vpotseluyko vpotseluyko     0 янв 22 00:19 localhost.2017-01-22.log
-rw-r----- 1 vpotseluyko vpotseluyko  3766 янв 21 23:52 localhost_access_log.2017-01-21.txt
-rw-r----- 1 vpotseluyko vpotseluyko   958 янв 22 00:56 localhost_access_log.2017-01-22.txt
-rw-r----- 1 vpotseluyko vpotseluyko     0 янв 21 21:32 manager.2017-01-21.log
-rw-r----- 1 vpotseluyko vpotseluyko     0 янв 22 00:19 manager.2017-01-22.log
```

в каком из них ошибки?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP статусы можно найти в `localhost_access_log`. Ошибки самого Tomcat находятся в `catalina`.